# How to run software with system start - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ps

I have a problem to set run software with system start. I have ubuntu 20.04. I tried to insert these lines to etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/clamonacc
```

it doesn't work. Second try was to insert it to cron like this:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/clamonacc
```

it also doesn't work. I am trying to check this by this command

```
ps -e | grep 'clam*'
```

In output there is nothing about clamonacc. If I run it manually as root, it works without any problem and I can find the running process in ps. Could someone help me how to debug this, where is the problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: maybe reformulate the question to ak about clamonacc specifically?

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.mail-archive.com/clamav-users@lists.clamav.net/msg48889.html, which links to a very detailed walk-through on clamav:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/clamonacc.service
[Unit]
Description=ClamAV On Access Scanner
Requires=clamav-daemon.service
After=clamav-daemon.service syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "while [ ! -S /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl ]; do sleep 
1; done"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/clamonacc -F --config-file=/etc/clamav/clamd.conf 
--log=/var/log/clamav/clamonacc.log --move=/root/quarantine

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am not sure if the mentioned directory is the right place - I'd rather go for /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants, where the clamd service resides (at least on my installation).